# Keycloak with vaadin and spring security

Tags: spring-security, vaadin7, keycloak

I want to secure my vaadin application with keycloak and spring security. I try to use the "keycloak-spring-security-adapter". 
My problem is that I want also unauthenticated users to use my application, but with less functionality - I do this with method security and checking which roles the current user has in the UI.

Can I configure the filter so that it ignores unauthenticated requests, but If the token is present uses it?

Thanks

Daniel

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you've got in your methods and UI? I haven't use Vaadin, but AFAIK everything is done there using Java (no XML-based structures for views), isn't it?

Comment: Yes it's all in java. There is a vaadin servlet mapped to one url, "vaadin-pages" are send by ajax to the browser

Comment: Then you can use the standard way of accessing roles using spring security, and wrap your view generation code pieces into conditions to render what you want depending on what kind of access the user has.

Comment: @XtremeBiker : this is exactly what I want to do - my problem is that the filter either enforces authentication or ignores the token. I guess I do something wrong in the filter configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working example of what you want can be found in the [public-access branch of this github project](https://github.com/chvndb/keycloak-spring-vaadin-demo/tree/public-access). It does use Vaadin 8 though.

In essence, you can setup your application to be partially public, i.e. accessibly to unauthenticated user for certain parts and requires login for others, as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableVaadinSharedSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic().disable();
    http.formLogin().disable();
    http.csrf().disable();
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/vaadinServlet/UIDL/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/vaadinServlet/HEARTBEAT/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().permitAll();
    http
        .logout()
        .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler())
        .logoutUrl("/sso/logout").permitAll()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    http
        .addFilterBefore(keycloakPreAuthActionsFilter(), LogoutFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());
    http
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy());
  }
...
}
```

The line `http.anyRequest().permitAll();` is the most important where you configure the filter to just allow all requests. You could still update this to only allow public access to certain urls.

You can then use spring security annotations on methods/views/components to configure your fine-grained access control. E.g:

```
@SpringComponent
@Secured("ROLE_ANONYMOUS")
public class LoginOperation implements Runnable {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // login logic
  }
}
```

and

```
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
public class LogoutOperation implements Runnable {    
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // logout logic
  }
}
```